# Response 500 on creating WebProfile

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'am trying to create WebProfile. The code below worked for me for the last 8 days, and since today it returns response 500.

**PHP**

```
        $flowConfig = new \PayPal\Api\FlowConfig();       
        $flowConfig->setLandingPageType("Billing");       
        $flowConfig->setBankTxnPendingUrl($this->referer);
        $presentation = new \PayPal\Api\Presentation();
        $inputFields = new \PayPal\Api\InputFields();    
        $inputFields->setAllowNote(false)
            ->setNoShipping(1)
            ->setAddressOverride(0);
        // #### Payment Web experience profile resource
        $webProfile = new \PayPal\Api\WebProfile();
        // Name of the web experience profile. Required. Must be unique
        $webProfile->setName(uniqid())
            // Parameters for flow configuration.
            ->setFlowConfig($flowConfig)
            // Parameters for style and presentation.
            ->setPresentation($presentation)
            // Parameters for input field customization.
            ->setInputFields($inputFields);
        try {
            // Use this call to create a profile.
            $createProfileResponse = $webProfile->create($this->apiContext);
            $createProfileResponse = json_decode($createProfileResponse);
            $web_profile_id = $createProfileResponse->id;                
            return $web_profile_id;         
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
            return FALSE;
        }
```

**paypal.log:**

```
[08-10-2016 02:33:16] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response   
Status  : 500


[08-10-2016 02:33:16] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: Response 
Headers : HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error, Date: Sat, 08 Oct 2016 
14:33:06 GMT, Server: Apache, PROXY_SERVER_INFO: 
host=slcsbplatformapiserv3002.slc.paypal.com;threadId=495, Paypal-
Debug-Id: c6d80d6e1ffc8, Connection: close, Paypal-Debug-Id: 
c6d80d6e1ffc8, Set-Cookie:X-
PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D2718169431%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3D; Expires=Sat, 08 Oct 2016 15:03:06 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT, Vary: Authorization, Content-Length: 145, Content-Type: application/json, , 

 [08-10-2016 02:33:16] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http 
response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-
experience/web-profiles/. {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"c6d80d6e1ffc8"}

[08-10-2016 02:33:16] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG:
```

I've tryed [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payment-experience/CreateWebProfile.php) example and got same error. Creating end executing payments works perfectly, so the problem is only with the web profiles. Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, PayPal's sandbox is notorious for this.  It would be best for you to submit this to [PayPal MTS](https://www.paypal.com/mts).  They're the ones that need to fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I've submited this issue [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues) and I'am not alone with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an bug on PayPal side, now fixed. Issue tracked [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/678).